# Can I use mixin with an external module in my vuejs project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, external, vue-mixin

I have used mixin vue within my vue project and it worked pretty well. But, is there a way to use mixin with a external module? I would like to use a sepecfic component that is inside that module in order to reuse its behavirour.
The component uses the sfc with  and  tags. I´m wondering if there is an way to do something like that:

```
import external_compoment from 'module/ExternalComponent.vue"
```

Then, I would like to do something like this inside my component:

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  mixin:[external_component],
```

Is there an way to achieve that?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you make it generic so that both your current one + `ExternalComponent` can import it? You can also leave it global if you may need it often.

Comment: The external component is a third party library, then i should not touch its code.  I´m not sure if i understand your suggestions. Is your sugestion still valid for a third party import?

Comment: Hm I'm not sure, I'd say that it depends on the actual code that is being applied.